# Use vibrator on fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments

I am trying to use vibration in fragment but i am getting error in context. How I can use this in a Fragment? Thank you This is my code:

```
Vibrator v = (Vibrator) this.context.getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);
v.vibrate(500);
```

Comment: Instead of `this.context` try `getApplicationContext()`.

Comment: getActivity().getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this code

```
Vibrator v = (Vibrator) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);
```

or

```
Vibrator v = (Vibrator) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);
```